# How make button in NSWindow clickable while a sheet's on top of it

Tags: cocoa, themes, nsview, nswindow, appkit

I have created a custom (themed) NSWindow, by creating a borderless window and then recreating all elements of the window border/background inside the content view. I've created the window widgets (close box, zoom box, minimize box) on top of my own fake title bar using -standardWindowButton:forStyleMask:.

Trouble is, when a sheet is presented on top of my custom window (e.g. "save changes...", those buttons do not receive the clicks.

Does anybody know how I can tell NSWindow not to intercept the clicks in my minimize box? It works with a standard NSWindow. When a sheet is up, I can still send both of them to the dock, or zoom the window out.

Answer (score 0):

I thought maybe there's special code in the content view that ignores clicks in subviews while a sheet is up. But it seems as if -hitTest: *is* called on the content view and returns the minimize widget, but the widget's action never gets triggered.

I guess I could just replace the content view and perform the action in the content view's hitTest if it is the minimize widget ... but that seems a bit ugly.

Comment: It would not surprise me if that's exactly how Apple do it.